# Shader storage block name issue

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Something weird is happening with my shader storage blocks.
I have 2 SSBs:

```
#version 450 core

out vec4 out_color;

layout (binding = 0, std430) buffer A_SSB
{
    float a_data[];
};

layout (binding = 1, std430) buffer B_SSB
{
    float b_data[];
};

void main()
{
    a_data[0] = 0.0f;
    a_data[1] = 1.0f;
    a_data[2] = 2.0f;
    a_data[3] = 3.0f;

    b_data[0] = 90.0f;
    b_data[1] = 81.0f;
    b_data[2] = 72.0f;
    b_data[3] = 63.0f;

    out_color = vec4(0.0f, 0.8f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

This is working well, but if i swap the SSB names like that:

```
layout (binding = 0, std430) buffer B_SSB
{
    float a_data[];
};

layout (binding = 1, std430) buffer A_SSB
{
    float b_data[];
};
```

the SSB indexes are swapped although they are hardcoded and data which should be written to a_data is written to b_data and vice versa.
Both SSBs are 250MB large, the max size is more than 2GB. It seems that the indexes are allocated alphabetical but this shouldn't happen. I'm binding the buffers like that:

```
glCreateBuffers(1, &a_ssb);
glNamedBufferStorage(a_ssb, 7187400 * 9 * sizeof(float), nullptr, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);

glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, a_ssb);
glShaderStorageBlockBinding(test_prog, 0, 0);

glCreateBuffers(1, &b_ssb);
glNamedBufferStorage(b_ssb, 7187400 * 9 * sizeof(float), nullptr, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);

glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, b_ssb);
glShaderStorageBlockBinding(test_prog, 1, 1);
```

Is this a bug or my fault? Also i would like to ask why i'm getting the error "lvalue in array access too complex or possible array index out of bounds" if i'm assigning values in a for loop?

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    a_data[i] = float(i);
```

Comment: Regarding the second issue: What happens if you rewrite the loop as `for(unsigned int i = 0; i < a_data.length(); ++i)` instead?

Comment: Display driver is crashing

Comment: In hindsight, I should have realized that would happen. Display Drivers will crash if a single task takes more than 2-5 seconds (depending on how your OS is configured) to execute. XD But presumably, the shader compiles successfully with that code, unlike in the previous code where it was showing an error?

Comment: Yes it compiles

Comment: for(unsigned int i = 0; i < (a_data.length() / a_data.length()) * 4; ++i) works and is the same as for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> glShaderStorageBlockBinding(test_prog, 0, 0);
> ```

This is your problem.

You assigned the binding index in the shader. You *do not* need to assign it again.

Your problem comes from the fact that you assigned it *incorrectly*.

The [second parameter to this function](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glShaderStorageBlockBinding.xhtml) is the index of the block you are assigning a binding index to. The *only way* to get a correct index is to query it via [Program Introspection APIs](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Program_Introspection). The block index is the [resource index](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Program_Introspection#Resource_indices), queried through this call:

```
auto block_index = glGetProgramResourceIndex​(test_prog, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, "A_SSB");
```

It just so happened, in your original code, that the shader compiler assigned `A_SSB`'s resource index to 0 and `B_SSB`'s resource index to 1. This assignment was probably arbitrarily done based on their names. Thus, when you changed the names on them, the resource indices didn't change. So `A_SSB` was still resource index 0, but your shader assigned it binding index 1. Which was fine...

Until your C++ code *overrode* that assignment with your `glShaderStorageBlockBinding(test_prog, 0, 0)`. That assigned resource index 0 (`A_SSB`) to binding index 0.

You should either set the binding index in the shader or in C++ code. Not in *both*.